# Location API Push or Poll

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gps

I've a handful of devices that I wish to track their GPS location in real time.
(Just imagine the pizza-delivery scenario)

Now that I want to view a map on the server side, showing all devices on the move.

Should I make each and every devices updating the server of their where-about in every few minutes, then store it in DB so we could plot it on the map later?
Is this a common way of how people tracking devices?

Or should we do poll instead - server only asks the targeted device(s) to send back their current location when they are needed? (Not sure if this is even possible)

Advise please?

P/S: Targeted devices are running Android/iOS, in-case you need to know.

Comment: Do you need to make a report of who-was-where? if not keep sending the location to the server from the device and update the record in the server. I had to show the report, in one of my projects so I had to save every bit of information. In the end it all comes to what your requirements are.

Comment: I just need the current location of the devices. History is nice to have, but not important here.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are possible and worth considering. That depends a lot on your requirements and your devices' capabilities.

If you want to plot the map later, you will obviously need the trackers to send their position at least whenever they move.

Polling the data when you need it will make sure they are always up to date, but you can't reliably plot them later.

You might even use a combination of both:
Let the devices send their position every few minutes and store them in a db. When you need the data, check if they are current enough (i.e. not older than 2 minutes) and if not, fetch the current position from the tracker.

If this is possible depends on your kind of tracker and how you talk to it. A good one should support it though.

Comment: But how do we poll for a particular device's location? For example on the server-side: GetDeviceLocation(DeviceID)
How do we send this message to the targeted device to make it send back current location? (I'm not a mobile developer, a pointer of how to achieve this is very much appreciated)

Comment: That depends on your device. Check the documentation. There are hundreds of different devices of this kind, and they all work different (more or less).